# Env var required but not provided - dbt CLI

Tags: dbt

We have an environment variable set in dbtCloud called `DBT_SNOWFLAKE_ENV` that selects the right database depending on which environment is used.

At the moment, I'm trying to set up dbt CLI with VSCode. I created a `profiles.yml` file that looks like this:

```yaml
default:
  target: development
  outputs:
    development:
      type: snowflake
      account: skxxxx.eu-central-1

      user: <name>
      password: <pass>

      role: sysadmin
      warehouse: transformations_dw
      database: " {{ env_var('DBT_SNOWFLAKE_ENV', 'analytics_dev') }} "
      schema: transformations
      threads: 4
```

I added the `env_var` line after some suggestions but I realise that the environment variable still doesn't exist yet. The problem I see is that if I hardcode `analytics_dev` in that place (which makes sense), the error still persists.

I wouldn't want anybody who's going to use dbt to have to change the environment variable if they want to run something on production.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a source file for the variables on dbt cli - for example you would create a bash script called `set_env_var.sh` and then `source set_env_var.sh` in your terminal.

An example of the bash script would be:

```
export SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT=xxxxx
export SNOWFLAKE_USER=xxxxx
export SNOWFLAKE_ROLE=xxxx
export SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA=xxxx
export SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE=xxxxx
```

and in your `profiles.yml` you can add all the variables you want, for example..

```
warehouse: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE') }}"
database: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE') }}"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all younyou have to give hard code database name the other syntax is wrong. Secondly try to make a dynamic variable for environment and then use it like this when you want to use dbt, mean

**DBT snapshot --profile --vars $DBT_SNOWFLAKE_ENV  **
As when you run it can easily pick up from env.

Currently i am working on dbt with everything dynamic even the full profile is dynamic according to schema and db.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in my DBT model my variable was declared as part of `vars` within my `dbt_project.yml` file, so instead of accessing the variable like

`"{{ env_var('MY_VARIABLE') }}"`

I should have used:

`"{{ var('MY_VARIABLE') }}"`